# CSS background images suddenly disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a weird problem on this website:

http://shopshopme.com

When I open the website in Chrome, all CSS background images load normally but as soon as the page loads they suddenly disappear (as if the images are broken or something).

This only happens on Chrome (Mac and Windows), but doesn't happen on Chrome mobile or Chrome version 45 or less.

I noticed that if I hard-reload (ctrl+shift+R) the tab, the images don't disappear.

Is this a known Chrome bug?

Comment: Hi User, This is not a chrome bug. optimize your background and try it. i suggest try www.tinypng.com

Comment: Just an add-on, your scroll to top icon is not showing ;)

Comment: I would recommend to fix reactjs errors first. Aspecially about server rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index: 1` to `.homepage #header-bg-uae` and it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by applying `position: static;` to `#header-bg-uae`. This bug may be related to (or actually) [this](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=111218).